# An inequality for the measure of an intersection of subsets of $\mathbb S^1$

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I’m trying to solve the following problem:

> Suppose $A, B \subset \mathbb{S}^1 = \mathbb R / \mathbb Z$. Prove that there is a $y \in \mathbb S^1$ such that $\lambda((A+y)\cap B) \geq \lambda(A)\lambda(B)$ (where $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure).

We can assume $0 < \lambda(A) < 1$ and $0 < \lambda(B) < 1$, since otherwise the problem is trivial. But beyond that I’m really having trouble with this. Any suggestions or hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT:

Let $f$, $g$ be functions on $S^1$. Show that there exists $y$ such that

$$\int_{S^1} f(x+y) g(x) d x \ge \int_{S^1} f \cdot \int_{S^1} g$$

To see this, calculate

$$\int_{S^1} (\int_{S^1} f(x+y) g(x) dx )\ d y$$

$\bf{Added:}$ Here is an example when the all the sets $(A+y) \cap B$ have the same size $\mu(A) \mu(B)$. Divide the circle into $6$ equal arcs, take $A$ consisting of two oposite arcs, and $B$ of three "odd" arcs.

A similar example can be given when $\mu(A) = \frac{1}{a}$, $\mu(B) = \frac{1}{b}$, and $a$, $b$ are relatively prime integers. Divide the circle into $a b$ equal arcs, and take $A$ consisting of $b$ equally spaced arcs, $B$ of $a$ equally spaced arcs. By taking $A_k$ the disjoint union of $k$ translates of $A$, $B_l$ the disjoint union of translates of $B$, we can  get examples of sets of sizes $\frac{k}{a}$, $\frac{l}{b}$.

Comment: This does the trick perfectly. Thank you!

Comment: @D. Ford:  You are very welcome! It is a nice question.